# log files taking too much space

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In the db2/logs/NODE0000 filesystem there are 3 log files generated for each date daily each of 4 mb size. As it is taking too much space, will it be a good idea to delete log files older than 2 years. Besides I am not familier with the contents of the log files as I am not from db2 background, as what help will I get from them.I need to take a action before the filesystem runs out of space, kindly suggest. Also what command should I use in order to view the .LOG files.

Answer (score 1):

These are database transaction logs; they are required for ongoing operation of the database(s) as well as for database recovery after a crash or after restoring a backup.

There is nothing for a human to view in these files.

Generally it should be OK to delete the log files that are older than the most recent backup, unless your backup retention policy requires you to keep several generations of backups. In the latter case you will need to keep all log files from the beginning of the oldest retained backup image.

You may want to read more [about the log file management in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006085.html?lang=en).